# Change width and colour of scroll bar in UITableView, iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scrollbar

I could only find if one wants to display scroll bar or not using

```
tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES/NO;
```

but how can I customize the scroll bar for colour, width and if possible other features?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I got this idea from code snippets where one must find Google logo in MKMapKit and relocate it somewhere so that it remains visible. 
by following method one can set custom image to scroll bar of UItbaleview. But I found nothing on changing size of scroll bar.

```
-(void) ViewDidLoad
{
UIImageView *testView = [self.tableView.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    UIImage *Img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    [testView setImage:Img];
}
```

EDIT:
As suggested by Nekto you can use following to change width.

```
CGRect frame = testView.frame; 
frame.size.width = 10; //set any value you want.
testView.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can set only style of **scroll indicators:**

> The style of the scroll indicators.

```
@property(nonatomic) UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle indicatorStyle
```

**Styles:**

> Scroll Indicator Style
>   The style of the scroll indicators. You use these constants to set the value of the indicatorStyle style.

```
typedef enum {
    UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleDefault,
    UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack,
    UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite
} UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle;
```

**For example:**

```
tableView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nekto. I tried  tableView.UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack ; which gave compilation error "property UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle not found for UItableView". Am I missing something here?

Comment: Added example to my answer. Try it

Comment: It is working now. Thanks a lot friend. By the way I am huge fan of "Mir Publishers" and very happy to talk to someone from moscow.

Comment: greetings..!!, please see EDIT in my answer(we can change colour!!). Do you think by some method I can change size of scroll bar. (But I tried tempView.frame.size.width = 10;) but gave compilation error that width is not assignable property

Comment: try this : `CGRect frame = tempView.frame; frame.size.width = 10; tempView.frame = frame;`

Answer (score 7):

You can change the scroll indicator color using:

```
tableView.indicatorStyle=UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this great open source custom scrollbar to your project, its totally customisable:
https://github.com/BasheerSience/BRScrollBar

Comment: Thanks a lot basheer... wht i actually need i got it...So you deserve up vote...Thnks again

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the original scroll bar and scroll using your custom scroll bar.

```
– (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
```

can be used to scroll content, just add your custom bar to the table.

Comment: Thanks Manali for your response. I will need time to implement your suggestion. I will let you know I above method works for me.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3

collectionView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle.white

Answer (score 1):

Swift-3,4

**If you are not able to override method "scrollViewDidScroll" (may be you are using this for some other functionality, or paging), Try this !!**

```
func setScrollIndicatorColor(color: UIColor) {
        for view in self.tableView.subviews {
            if view.isKind(of: UIImageView.self),
                let imageView = view as? UIImageView,
                let _ = imageView.image  {
                imageView.image = nil
                view.backgroundColor = color
            }
        }

        self.tableView.flashScrollIndicators()
    }
```

in viewDidAppear() you can call this method.

Comment: doesn't work at all.

Comment: Did you call this method ??

Answer (score 0):

I did'n find any other way but this:

```
UITableView *v;
[v setIndicatorStyle:<#(UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle)#>];
```

There is only 3 available styles. If only you will find the way to implement your own UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle, but I can't even imagine HOW to do this: they are implemented deep in UIKit framework (declared in UIScrollView.h), and you can only set a flag, witch will used by UIScrollView to know, what style to use. So, I can't see any other way: you will need somehow to implement new style and flag there. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Thanks SentineL for your thoughts. For now I also can't think of any way of doing this, If I succeed in creating custom scroll bar I will let you know.

Comment: By the way:
Why do you need this? just customization, or some fuctionality? You may just implement new subView on the top of ScrollBar and do whatever you whant with it. it will just hide default indicator. But in this case, you will need to do alot of work to make this work nicely.

Comment: Hah! So, indicator is reachable, and it is at index 1? Greate! tnx for this comment

Answer (score 0):

change indicator color with 3 default color style.

TextField.indicatorStyle=UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;