# change the color of scrollbar in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, scrollbar

I have one `viewcontroller`.Inside that i placed one `tableview` with size `320X295` at `centre` of my viewcontroller. so my table view will be half size at centre in my `viewcontroller`.

**My tableview is not fully fill my Viewcontroller**.Now how can i change my `scroll bar` color to `green color` or some `RGB` Value.

Here is my code:

```
    UIScrollView *scView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scView.frame = self.view.bounds; //scroll view occupies full parent views
    scView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 400);
   // scView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    scView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack;

      scView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    scView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [self.containerTableView addSubview: scView];
```

`ContainerTableView` is my tableview name.

i need to change my scroll bar color to green.Please help me how can i achive that.Thanks

Comment: Why you are adding scrollview? Tableview itself have scrollview. if you want to change color then try to change tableview color.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change width and colour of scroll bar in UITableView, iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976593/change-width-and-colour-of-scroll-bar-in-uitableview-iphone)

Comment: @nadim thats wa i am asking ..already my tableview have scroll bar but i need to change the color of my scroll bar

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the property of `UIScrollView` named `indicatorStyle`

Use any of the following

```
typedef enum {
    UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleDefault,
    UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack,
    UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite
} UIScrollViewIndicatorStyle;
```

you can use this style like this.

tableView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleBlack;

here is the link for reference..

[Change width and colour of scroll bar in UITableView, iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976593/change-width-and-colour-of-scroll-bar-in-uitableview-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

**1 .Add UIScrollViewDelegate**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@end
```

**2. Add scrollViewDidScroll in implementation section**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
//get refrence of vertical indicator
UIImageView *verticalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-1)]);
//set color to vertical indicator
[verticalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // Your color

//get refrence of horizontal indicator
UIImageView *horizontalIndicator = ((UIImageView *)[scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:(scrollView.subviews.count-2)]);
//set color to horizontal indicator
[horizontalIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; // Your color
}
```