# How to override UICollectionVIew scroll indicators?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

a collectionview horizontal scroller indicator is a rectangle view, how to make it a bubble or some-other custom look? For eg right now it is rectangle how to make it a small round bubble?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976593/change-width-and-colour-of-scroll-bar-in-uitableview-iphone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change width and colour of scroll bar in UITableView, iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976593/change-width-and-colour-of-scroll-bar-in-uitableview-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the colors for example for the scrollbar using the following code:

```
tableView.indicatorStyle=UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
```

Besides that there is a library that enables you to do this quite easily:

> https://github.com/maximbilan/SwiftlyScrollSlider

Hope that helped fixing your issue! :)

Comment: thanks will check it out i think setting an image using that library should help

Comment: No worries mate!